# .htaccess url rewriting is not working it shows 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have URL like this `example.com/post/second.php?id=10`

I need a URL like this `example.com/post/second/10`

I'm trying to create `.htaccess` file in `/post/` folder and domain root folder but nothing is working.

My `.htaccess` code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^second/([0-9]+)$ /second.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: That will not work.  The URL is before the question mark.  After the question mark are parameters.  So the location of the file doesn't include anything after the question mark.

Comment: Can you clarify which URL you are linking to? (You should be linking to `/post/second/10`.) And do you have any other directives?

Comment: You probably need to turn `MultiViews` off, otherwise you will get a problem with the partial overlap between fake path (`second`) and existing file (`second.php`) here.

Answer (score 1):

You might try this in `/post/.htaccess`, as you have only file `/post/second.php`, but not `/second.php` as you call in your accessFile:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^second/([0-9]+)$ second.php?id=$1 [L]
```